# Adobe DTM/Sitecatalyst - Suggestion to capture all 3 cookie into one eVar

Tags: adobe

Anyone tried to capture all 3 cookie(mid, s_vi,s_fid) value in one eVar. If yes, any suggestion on the code.

The reason for capturing all 3 cookie in one evar is not to miss out each user unique ID's. And, this would help me to find the unique visitors count.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could capture each of these values into different Data Elements and then within the UI of a rule select the evar and string all three Data Elements together.  %dataElement1%%dataElement2%%dataElement3%

If you want some delimiter between the values like a comma you would add that in there like so:   %dataElement1%,%dataElement2%,%dataElement3%